# How can we define rules for identifying a certain sequence in a given series?

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I would like to know if is possible identify a certain sequence inside given a series.

`lex` produces three different tokens: `START`, `AMINO`, `STOP`.  I want to identify, by `YACC`, all the sequences which start with `START`, having a series of `AMINO` tokens, and end with `STOP`. Example: `START AMINO AMINO ... AMINO STOP`

I have never used `YACC/bison` before, so I have tried:

```
%%
seq_2: START seq_1 STOP {printf("%s", $2);};
seq_1: seq_1 AMINO
%%
```

But these rules don't work.

- Is it possible (and convenient) trying to solve this issue by `lex` and `YACC`?
- If it is possible, which could be a good way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Can you please elaborate? What should the semantic rule for `seq_1` be? And you are aware of that `seq_1` is an infinite recursion rule, there's nothing to stop it (which I *guess* is your problem)? Perhaps you should go find some good tutorial about YACC (there are thousands all over)? The Bison manual have a very good tutorial in itself.

Comment: The rules say: To build a `seq_2`, you need (among other things) a `seq_1` first. To build a `seq_1`, you also need a `seq_1` first. There's nothing to get you started; the grammar is impossible to satisfy.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is about how to write a rule which specifies how to find a sequence delimited by `START` and `STOP`. I have read some tutorial and handbook, but I have not clear yet how to implement this set of rules in `YACC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting an error because there's no semicolon at the end of your 'seq_1' rule. E.g:

```
seq_1 : seq_1 AMINO ;
```

Also, as you currently have it it's impossible for seq_1 to ever terminate. You can fix that by giving it an additional rule which is terminal.

If it is valid for 'seq_1' to be empty then you can do that as follows:

```
seq_1 : seq_1 AMINO ;
seq_1 : ;
```

Or, as it is more typically written:

```
seq_1 : seq_1 AMINO
      |
      ;
```

If there should always be at least one AMINO between START and STOP then do it this way:

```
seq_1 : AMINO
      | seq_1 AMINO
      ;
```